# Prevent adding same Document to Array where only timestamps differ using Mongoose and Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Is there a way to prevent adding duplicate documents in an array that only have different timestamps with the $addToSet function?

So say i have an array:

```
Schools: [
  {
    Name: 'Jack High',
    State: 'DC',
    created: '2019-05-02 11:03:35.344'
  }
]
```

I want to prevent thee addition of :

```
{
    Name: 'Jack High',
    State: 'DC',
    created: '2019-05-05 11:03:35.344'
 }
```

because it has the same values just different create dates.

Any ideas of how to do this using Express and mongoose